# Why isn't memset working as expected?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

I have the below program:(functionality: pads white spaces to the right of string,used astreix here for visual ease):

os:windows(visual studio)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define CBUFFSIZE 48

void right_pad_str(char *pad_str, char *buff,int max_buffsize){

   int padstr_len = 0;
   int space_len = 0;
   char *end_str = NULL;

   memset(buff, '\0', max_buffsize);
   padstr_len = strlen(pad_str);
   space_len = ((max_buffsize - 1) - padstr_len);

   strncpy_s(buff, max_buffsize, pad_str, strlen(pad_str));

   end_str = buff +padstr_len;

   memset((end_str), '*', space_len);

   buff[max_buffsize] = '\0';

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    char tmpstr[49] = { '\0' };
    char *str = "hello_world";

    right_pad_str(str, tmpstr, CBUFFSIZE + 1);

    return 0;
 }
```

There seems to be an issue at memset when I look at the value post memeset, it looks very incorrect i.e junk why is this?In the end I null terminate the string yet I see junk value and a stack corruption error, not sure what's wrong with my logic.

(I have attached a snapshot of the same)

[image: memset invalid value]

Comment: "In the end I null terminate the string" Your screenshot shows that the line which nul-terminates the string hasn't executed yet.

Comment: I null terminate it for added safety I memset it right in the beginning,yet I see garbage in the string

Comment: Yes but the string isn't null terminated yet. It'll be one line later.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e52b67389ca97717 And I don't see any mistake on first glance (other than that `buff[max_buffsize] = '\0';` is out of bounds). Try to watch the variable `buff[48]` and check which line changes it from 0 to something else.

Comment: `buff[max_buffsize] = '\0';` writes outside `buff[]` --> undefined behavior.

Comment: okay that fixed the stack corruption issue, but I'm a little puzzled here, my buff size is 48 but if you look at the picture after memset it says strlen(buff) is 63?i.e it's as though accessing some junk location? also why should I be doing an explicit null termination here? shouldn't memset already have take care of it?i.e memset (49 chars to null) fill 48 then return, rather than voluntarily setting the last character to null?

Comment: You want to read the fine print at the bottom of the documentation for the function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43.aspx `The debug versions of these functions first fill the buffer with 0xFD. To disable this behavior, use _CrtSetDebugFillThreshold`  Check your math carefully, you're placing your null terminator after the last 0xfd in the buffer.

Comment: "I'm a little puzzled here, my buff size is 48" --> looks like 49 to me with `char tmpstr[49]` and `CBUFFSIZE + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unexpected behaviour can be seen in this simpler example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[3];
    buffer[0] = '\0';
    buffer[1] = '\0';
    buffer[2] = '\0';
    strncpy_s(buffer, 3, "*", 1);
    printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)(unsigned char)buffer[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 254 rather than 0, but only in a debug build.  This happens during the call to `strncpy_s`, which is unexpectedly writing to the destination buffer past the end of the copy, presumably in order to expose bugs such as the one (already pointed out) in your code.

---

**NB:** Retired Ninja quite correctly points out (in the comments to the question) that this is described, slightly inaccurately, in [the documentation's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43(v=vs.100).aspx) fine print, which I'd originally overlooked:

> The debug versions of these functions first fill the buffer with 0xFD. To disable this behavior, use _CrtSetDebugFillThreshold.

(In fact, in Visual Studio 2010, at least, it fills the buffer with 0xFE.)

Comment: What does 254 have to do with 0xFD?  Looks like an off-by-1 situation.

Comment: @chux, my guess would be a typo in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[@Harry Johnston](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45992434/2410359) fine answer explains what went wrong.

---

To pad a string to its array size, recommend:

1) Dispense with the excessive writing of `'\0'` (`memset(buff, ...);... strncpy_s(buff,...`) that are subsequently written with data.

2) Use `size_t` for indexing arrays and *string* math.  `size_t` is the right size integer for the job.

3) Watch out for badly form calls like with a pad longer than the target or a call with a size of 0.  Could check for `NULL` pointers too.

```
void right_pad_str(const char *pad_str, char *buff, size_t buff_size){ 
  if (buff_size > 0) {
    size_t pad_size = strlen(pad_str) + 1;
    if (pad_size > buff_size) {
      pad_size = buff_size;
    }

    memcpy(buff, pad_str, pad_size - 1); 
    memset(&buff[pad_size - 1], '*', buff_size - pad_size);
    buff[buff_size - 1] = '\0';
  }
}

// usage
right_pad_str(str, tmpstr, sizeof tmpstr);
```